# How to resize and crop an image with CSS, inside a Bootstrap Card?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-cards

Following problem: I have some Bootstrap card elements with pictures, and some pictures have different sizes/ratios, like the one in the middle (see attached screenshot). Therefore my card elements are not in one row. That's not very nice.

Now I would like to resize these images to the height of the others, and crop the overflow. How do i do that? Heres my code snippet of one card...

```
<div id="cities">
  <div class="city">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="city-img-container">
        <img class="card-img-top city-img" src="..." alt="New York City">
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title"><b>Name: </b>New York City</h5>
        <p class="card-text"><b>Land: </b>USA<br>
            <b>Spitzname: </b>The Big Apple</p>
        <div class="city-bottom-content">
            <a href="#/city?id=35" class="btn btn-primary" data-id="35">
              <i class="bi bi-arrow-right"></i>
            </a>
            <button data-id="35" class="is-favorite">
              <i class="bi bi-heart-fill"></i> 
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="city">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

PS: The card elements inside of #cities are arranged with grid and grid-template-columns.

Thank uuu! :)

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EPPo.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make all of the images the same height (and width) by using object-fit.

```
.card-img-top {
    width: 100%;
    height: 15vw;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

In the example above, the height of all images will be 15% of the viewport width. This could be whatever you please...`500px`, `10vh`, etc.

The `object-fit: cover;`, will likely hide parts of images - but perhaps you could implement a means of viewing them in full-size when clicked on? Either way, it's a nice approach to keep the cards fairly uniform.

Note that you are just making some adjustments to the existing Bootstrap class `.card-img-top`. You could include this CSS on your HTML file, in your CSS file, or update the class in your Bootstrap file if you downloaded it.

Comment: Ps, this won't distort your image or mess up the aspect ratio.
Also, this will ensure images that are taller or wider will both fit nicely. It's less handy if an image is super tall or wide as more of the image will be cropped.

Comment: That's exactly, what I wanted to have. Thanks a lot, @AyyCee! :)

Answer (score 0):

Give a fixed height to image tag so small images will automatically expand.

```
<img class="card-img-top city-img" height="200px" src="..." alt="New York City">
```